# SDO_BUFFER does not work in Oracle XE

Tags: oracle-xe

I'm working with
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition 11.2.0.3.0 64bit Production ("EE") and
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition 11.2.0.2.0  64bit Production ("XE").

The following query

```
select 
  sdo_geom.sdo_buffer(
     mdsys.sdo_geometry(2002,NULL,NULL, 
        mdsys.sdo_elem_info_array(1,2,1),
        mdsys.sdo_ordinate_array(10,10,15,15)
     ), 
     10, 0.0005
  ) 
from dual;
```

does work in EE, but not in XE. EE correctly returns:

```
MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY(2003,NULL,NULL,MDSYS.SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1,1005,4,1,2,1,3,2,2,7,2,1,9,2,2),MDSYS.SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(17.0710678118655,2.92893218813453,22.0710678118655,7.92893218813453,22.0710678118655,22.0710678118655,7.92893218813453,22.0710678118655,2.92893218813453,17.0710678118655,2.92893218813452,2.92893218813453,17.0710678118655,2.92893218813453))
```

XE, however, returns just the unmodified geometry:

```
MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY(2002,NULL,NULL,MDSYS.SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1,2,1),MDSYS.SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(10,10,15,15))
```

According to [Oracle Locator Documentation, Table B-1](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e11830/sdo_locator.htm#SPATL340), the SDO_GEOM.SDO_BUFFER function is also part of Oracle Locator and XE. What could be the reason for the different behaviour?